# magic GET and SET for object initialization question

Tags: c#-4.0, domain-driven-design

I would like to know the best practice for a class oriented DDD.

Since i am doing domain validation in custom setters named ChangeX(string x) i might be pushed to use this as property.

> public virtual string example { get;
>   private set; }

However, that not very good since it disable me from using the object initialization feature such as :

> new Object { Example = "Some example"
>   }

So i though why not passing the custom set into the property set ? like this

> public virtual string Example { get {
>   return Example; } set {
>   ChangeExample(value); } }

Is this can lead to any problems ? it is against best practices ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Real problem here is using setters as such. Why do You need them?

When You use setters, You lose isolation - You can modify state of objects from outside w/o them knowing that. That leads to procedural code.

In contrast - You should ask objects to do something (not just modify their state) that would eventually might lead to them changing their own state.

Comment: Which setters your talking about ? these ones ? public virtual string example { get; private set; }

Comment: @Rushino Private setters are fine. If it's private, You aren't exposing ability to modify state from outside. I'm talking about public ones.

Comment: @Rushino You shouldn't use object initialization feature either. You should define precise constructors. Through them You can guarantee that domain object will be constructed valid.

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution is fine. One reason to have setters is to make sure your under laying fields never hold incorrect values.